# SQL Server 2008 - Get the bottom most linked record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, logic

I have the following data in my SQL Server database:

```
Id | Name | LinkedId
---+------+----------
1  | A    | 1
2  | B    | 2
3  | C    | 1
4  | D    | 3
5  | E    | 4
```

Now I want to write a stored procedure in which the following record should be shown:

**Note**: `LinkedId` has the Id that is associated with that name.

**For example**: "C" is associated with "A"

```
Id | Name | LinkedId
---+------+---------
1  | A    | 1
2  | B    | 2
3  | C    | 1
4  | D    | 1 //here instead of showing 3, it showed 1 which is the bottom most value in the tree
5  | E    | 1 //same case as the above
```

**PROBLEM**:

For this scenario according to my limited knowledge I can only think of using JOINS (LEFT, INNER) but that won't be enough in this case to get the bottom most linked id of it.

**EDIT** (OUTPUT):

I want all the items associated (directly and indirectly) with item "C"

```
Id | Name | 
---+------+
3  | C    | 
4  | D    | 
5  | E    |
```

Comment: why do you want to update the bottom two rows as 1.I am not clear.

Comment: @Kapil it changed because if we take the case of name "D", its ID is 4 and its linked ID is 3 and if you see the linked ID 3, its sub-linked id is 1 and if you look at ID 1 then it is 1 (it cannot further continue). I need to get the bottom most value of it.                Hope i make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive function

A simple explain, recursive function using CTE is a `common table expression` that uses itself on caculating. It includes:

> 1. Invocation of the routine.
>
> The first invocation of the recursive CTE
>   consists of one or more CTE_query_definitions joined by UNION ALL,
>   UNION, EXCEPT, or INTERSECT operators.
>
> Because these query definitions
>   form the base result set of the CTE structure, they are referred to as
>   anchor members.
>
> CTE_query_definitions are considered anchor members
>   unless they reference the CTE itself.
>
> All anchor-member query
>   definitions must be positioned before the first recursive member
>   definition, and a UNION ALL operator must be used to join the last
>   anchor member with the first recursive member.
>
> 2. Recursive invocation of the routine.
>
> The recursive invocation includes one or more
>   CTE_query_definitions joined by UNION ALL operators that reference the
>   CTE itself. These query definitions are referred to as recursive
>   members.
>
> 3. Termination check.
>
> The termination check is implicit;
>   recursion stops when no rows are returned from the previous
>   invocation.

Reference link: [Recursive query using CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Simple Example of Recursive CTE](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/)
  [Cte sql server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE (Id int, Name varchar(10), LinkedId int)

INSERT INTO @SampleData 
VALUES (1, 'A', 1), (2, 'B', 2), 
(3, 'C', 1),(4, 'D', 3),(5, 'A', 4)

;WITH temp AS 
(
   SELECT sd.Id, sd.Name,  sd.Id AS RootId 
   FROM @SampleData sd WHERE sd.LinkedId = sd.Id -- Invocation of the routine, in this case it's root node of tree.

   UNION ALL
   -- Recursive invocation of the routine
   SELECT sd.Id, sd.Name,  t.RootId AS RootId  
   FROM temp t
   INNER JOIN @SampleData sd ON sd.LinkedId = t.Id AND sd.LinkedId <> sd.Id
   -- Termination check: sd.LinkedId = t.Id AND sd.LinkedId <> sd.Id. 
   -- It make recursive query is not an infinitive loop
)
SELECT  t.Id, t.Name, t.RootId AS LinkedId
FROM temp t
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- this option remove recursive max depth, default is 100.
```

### Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/MOTPZ27558)

For new output, you could change `The first invocation of the
recursive CTE`

```
;WITH temp AS 
(
   SELECT sd.Id, sd.Name,  sd.Id AS RootId 
   FROM @SampleData sd WHERE sd.Id = 3

   UNION ALL
   -- Recursive invocation of the routine
   SELECT sd.Id, sd.Name,  t.RootId AS RootId  
   FROM temp t
   INNER JOIN @SampleData sd ON sd.LinkedId = t.Id AND sd.LinkedId <> sd.Id
   -- Termination check: sd.LinkedId = t.Id AND sd.LinkedId <> sd.Id. 
   -- It make recursive query is not an infinitive loop
)
SELECT  t.Id, t.Name, t.RootId AS LinkedId
FROM temp t
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- this option remove recursive max depth, default is 100.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you explain how does this work in detail?

Comment: thanks for the edit and i am sorry for asking more and more but can you edit the solution to get all the related items who are under the Item "C" which should be item "C","D" and "E"

Comment: Please check the updated output..........Please help me get the new output but make sure that item "A" doesn't make it to the output list because i want all the items which are under "C".

Comment: Sorry my friend but i tried and it seems that "EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SampleData sd2 
                    WHERE sd2.Id = sd2.LinkedId 
                    AND sd2.Id = sd.LinkedId)" is useless because whatever value i change "1" to the answer remains the same.

Comment: Condition `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SampleData sd2 WHERE sd2.Id = sd2.LinkedId AND sd2.Id = sd.LinkedId)`  checks this node is direct child of root node. I try my query and it returns your desired result.

Comment: try changing that "1" to "10000" and the answer still remains the same.

Comment: You don't understand what these lines code mean. I change it directly Id = 3 (node C)

Answer (score 0):

You want a recursive procedure:

```
with cte as (
      select t.id, t.name, t.linkedid, 1 as lev
      from t
      where t.linkedid = t.id
      union all
      select t.id, t.name, cte.linkedid, cte.lev + 1
      from t join
           cte
           on cte.id = t.linkedid and t.linkedid <> t.id
     )
select id, name, linkedid
from cte;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/TAHX62040) is it working in practice.

Comment: thanks for trying mate but it is not working. It gives me error message "The multi-part identifier "t.linkedid" could not be bound." and YES i changed "linkedid" with the real field name.

Comment: @Agent_Spock . . . There is no error message based on names of columns.  A working version is shown.  The original version did go into an infinite loop because it did not filter out the root notes in the recursive part (hence the `t.linkedid <> t.id` condition).